# Dynamic scheduling of data driven subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a data driven subscription which delivers a report to an email alias at specific time.
In a subscription query:

```
select WorkProjectionReportTime,WorkProjectionReportToMailAlias,
'Work Projection Report for the period ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE()-31,101)+ ' to '+CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE()-1,101) as Subject,
CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE()-31,101) as FromDate,CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE()-1,101) as ToDate, 60 as WO, 
'Please see the attachment for the details' as body
from tblConfig
Pivot ( MAX(cValue) for cKey in (WorkProjectionReportTime,WorkProjectionReportToMailAlias) ) as xyz
```

So by query I get all the required fields, Email To, Time, report parameters.

I want to use the time parameter to schedule report.
e.g. if time is 9:30 the report should be mailed at 9:30 AM etc.
I want to achieve this from SQL or database front and not from C#. How to achieve this?

Comment: From what I understand, you want to base the report delivery off of WorkProjectReportTime, which comes from tblConfig. How often would the value of WorkProjectionReportTime for a report change? Are there processes that change the values in tblConfig at regular intervals?

Comment: You got it right. The value in tblConfig is configurable from Web UI by user. He can set any value any time in HH:MM format only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined with a scheduling table suggested above, you can use the following to send a report via TSQL, using @report_path as your parameter:

```
SELECT 'exec ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType=''TimedSubscription'', 
             @EventData=''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), rs.SubscriptionID) + ''''
FROM   ReportServer.dbo.Catalog c,
       ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule rs,
       ReportServer.dbo.Schedule s
WHERE      rs.ReportID = c.ItemID
       AND rs.ScheduleID = s.ScheduleID
       AND c.path = @report_path
       AND s.RecurrenceType = 1 -- only the ones with the regular scheduling disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create job that runs each minute and checks whether there are reports to send and sends them. But it means that you will have delay of maximum 1 minute + "how long it takes for your report to run".

Further more

1. you can put report sending in service Broker and it will make sure that reports are sent asynchronously to your schedule checker job.

or

1. Create queuing table for report sending, and main job will insert send requests to it.
   Additionally you can have 5 jobs that read 1-2 requests and sends them, but in this case you delay as job schedule.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does SSRS work on Service broker concepts?
Because I'm finding it hard to use my own Schedule table and invoke the Event